# JQuery : Inserting into newly created elements

Tags: jquery

I have this code (running jQuery 1.4.2)

```
var elementToAdd = $('<h3>').html('header');
var p = $('<p>').html('hello world');
elementToAdd.after(p);
$('div#content').append(elementToAdd);
```

However, the output is

```
<div id="content">
  <h3>header</h3>
</div>
```

The paragraph "Hello world" is not added.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I have been trying out some variations:

This does not work either:

```
var elementToAdd = $('<div>Header</div>');
var p = $('<p>hello world</p>');
elementToAdd.after(p);
```

or this:

```
var elementToAdd = $('<h3>header</h3>').after('<p>hello world</p>');
```

But this works (on Firefox, at least):

```
var elementToAdd = $('<div>').after('<h3>header</h3>').after('<p>hello world</p>');
```

Why?

Comment: that doesn't make any sense, after() what? elementToAdd needs to exists for definition of after to be valid over it

Comment: I am trying this after reading that jQuery 1.4.2 allows chaining after on disconnected DOM nodes.

Comment: can you point to say, a link where you read that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/after/, the section on "Inserting Disconnected DOM nodes". The sample code there works, so I guess you have to insert an empty div first for it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** To modify the original set, you can `.push()` a DOM element (not a jQuery object) into the set.

```
var elementToAdd = $('<h3>').html('header');
var p = $('<p>').html('hello world');

   // Push the DOM element in
elementToAdd.push( p[0] );   // [0] gets the DOM element at index 0
$('div#container').append( elementToAdd );​
```

---

Instead of `.after()`, use jQuery's [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method.

```
var elementToAdd = $('<h3>').html('header');
var p = $('<p>').html('hello world');

 // Add the new object ----------------v
$('div#container').append( elementToAdd.add(p) );​
```

This will append it as a sibling like you want.

It returns a new jQuery object with both elements as siblings. Because it doesn't modify the original object, you need to either call it in the `.append()` or store the result in a variable to append.

---

**EDIT:** *(As noted in another answer, you can now use `after()` like `add()`, in that it returns a new set and doesn't modify the original.)*

To explain why, this is because a jQuery object is an Array of DOM elements. A DOM element can be a single element with nested descendants, but not two siblings. So when you do `.after()`, you're trying to add a sibling to *each* single element in the array.

To deal with siblings, jQuery has them stored as additional items in its Array.

So when you create a jQuery object by passing 2 or more sibling elements, it splits them apart, and makes them separate items in the Array.

```
var $obj = $("<div>div element</div> <span>span element</span>");
```

This will give you a jQuery object with an Array of 2 items.

```
$obj[0] is the <div> element
$obj[1] is the <span> element
```

So if you were to create them separately, you would need to use `.add()` to add the new item to the Array.

```
var $obj = $("<div>div element</div>");

$obj[0] is the <div>

var $span = $("<span>span element</span>");
$obj = $obj.add( $span );

$obj[0] is the <div>
$obj[1] is the <span>
```

Comment: Using add() works, though reading the API it gives me the impression that it is more expensive than DOM insertion methods. Am I right?

Comment: @Extrakun - Deleted previous comment. It looks like `.after` is now able to behave in a manner similar to `.add()` in that it returns a new object with both elements, so you would need to overwrite the old `elementToAdd` value with the new: `elementToAdd = elementToAdd.after(p);`

Comment: I guess this raises the question of using after() vs. add(). insert() is listed as DOM insertion, while add() is traversal. I guess that should be another question though :D

Comment: @Extrakun - I think they ultimately are doing the same thing. They both call the inner `pushStack` method. And both are (in my opinion) equally confusing in that they don't modify the original set like one would expect (again in my opinion).

Comment: @Extrakun - ...here's a third option. Because a jQuery object is an Array, you can use the Array's `.push()` method. But be aware, you need to `.push()` the DOM element in. Not the jQuery object. This will give you a modified set like you expect, but also be aware that you won't be able to chain after `.push()`. Shouldn't be an issue since you have a variable reference. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think `.after` works with elements that have not been added to the DOM yet...

Try this

```
var elementToAdd = $('<h3>').html('header');
var p = $('<p>').html('hello world');
$('div#content').append(elementToAdd);
elementToAdd.after(p);
```

**Edit:** Yep, that works alright! http://jsfiddle.net/tu2GY/

**Edit 2:** ok, I am not extremely good at this, but here goes...

As @Extrakun pointed out, the jQuery documentation indeed notes that the element may not be attached to the DOM...

> As of jQuery 1.4, `.before()` and `.after()` will also work on disconnected DOM nodes.

So, I took a deep breath and opened jquery-1.4.2.js (in vim :D) and what I found was that whatever is being passed to `.after` on an element that has **no** `parentNode`, is being used as a selector **string** which I think is failing when you are passing a jQuery object. I'll try to post some code of what I mean <strike>in a minute or two</strike> here... (inside `pushStack` method)

```
ret.selector = this.selector + "." + name + "(" + selector + ")";
```

The `selector` here is what ends up being whatever you pass to `.after`. Didn't really make out much after that.

Comment: ha! It helps me think of jQuery as *not-a-black-box* ;)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. Adding a temporary works:

```
var e = $('<h3>').html('header');
var p = $('<p>').html('hello world');
var result = e.after(p);
$('div#content').append(result);
```

...So I'm guessing that `e.after(p)` *returns* "p after e", but *doesn't* actually change e. So it works in a chain, and it works disconnected, but won't work quite the way you're expecting it to work.

Comment: +1 weee! That explains what I saw in the jQuery source code, the `pushStack` method makes a new object and returns that, which represents both the elements.

Comment: Looks like you're right. If there's no parent node, it now pushes the object in, returning a new set. http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L146

Answer (score 0):

'elementToAdd' is not a jQuery object pointing to the element. try this:

```
var elementToAdd = $('<h3>');
elementToAdd.html('header');
var p = $('<p>').html('hello world');
$('div#content').append(elementToAdd);
elementToAdd.after(p);
```

Comment: No. It is a jquery object pointing to the element. **Edit:** That's why chaining works :)

Comment: var x = $('a#someID').attr('href'); // this will return the value inside the href, x will not point to the <a> element. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's the behaviour of `.attr`. But `.html` allows chaining and hence, does return the jQuery object. In fact, if you call `.attr` with two arguments, you get a jQuery object and hence chaining still works...

Comment: Let me put it this way, when you call `.attr('href')` you are *expecting* a non-jQuery object and you don't *intend* to do chaining after that `.attr` call. But for `.html` with arguments, you are *setting* something, not *getting*, hence the return value is the jQuery object to facilitate further chaining... hope that makes it clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating dom is an expensive operation and its best to do it minimum number of times, you above code can be very easily changed to,

```
$('div#content').append('<h3>header</h3><p>hello world</p>');
```

Comment: That was just an example. The real code involves dynamically writing out strings fetched from a DB and setting up an link with a function callback...

Comment: still you can use concatenation to create a single string and then pass it on to the append function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, inserting disconnected DOM nodes with .before and .after only works in jQuery 1.4 (and derivatives).

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script>
  $('<div/>').after('<p>Test</p>').filter('p').appendTo('body');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all recent jQuery versions, you can also use an object that gets appended for inserting DOM nodes:

```
<script>
  $("<span/>", {
    class: "test",
    html: "<p><b>Click me!</b></p>"
  }).appendTo( "body" );
</script>
```